# Single word that could mean three other words

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms

I would like to know whether there's a word which could mean these 3 things:

- Support
- Like
- Congratulate

I hoping to use it in my website for user's status. I would really appreciate if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: '!' is interpreted in many ways. But this question is hardly likely to produce answers of use to the general public.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is hardly likely to produce answers of use to many other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that there exists a single word in the English language that spans all these three meanings in its dictionary definitions.

But one that might fit the bill loosely is "**kudos**".

> praise or respect that you get because of something you have done or achieved [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kudos).

However, on Facebook, "**like**" is at least *used* in ways that mean all three things.

For instance, when somebody on Facebook reports that their cat has just died, friends of the person will typically press "like".  I've always interpreted this as signs of support and sympathy - not actually *liking* that the cat died.

So one option, given Facebook's dominance in this field, is to adopt their overloading of the word "like".

In David Eggers' social media satire [The Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Circle_%28Eggers_novel%29), the word "**smile**" is used in user's status updates for *anything* that is positive, congratulatory and/or supportive.  So another option is to adopt this word from Eggers' novel.

Comment: A remarkably good answer to an almost impossible question!

Answer (score 1):

FreeRadical's suggestion of "like!" is brilliant. IN the same vein, I suggest

> Thumbs Up!

You could possibly also use, with an exclamation point, just "Yes!"

Finally, sometimes people use "this", just like that, to mean essentially "I wholeheartedly agree, that's the way to go regarding the problem at hand."